# Trigger in Oracle: error during execution of trigger

Tags: sql, oracle

here I show us what happen when I tried to see if my trigger works.
I have 2 tables: contracts_aux and matches.

team is a NUMBER(1) from 0 to 9.

Attribute team in MATCHES have to be the same of this player in contracts or 1 less or 1 more. (In matches, the same player could appear more than one time).

```
SQL> select * from contracts_aux;
PLAYER                     TEAM
-------------------- ----------
Peter                         5
Mark                          7
SQL> select * from matches;
PLAYER                     TEAM      MATCH
-------------------- ---------- ----------
Peter                         5         99
Peter                         4         92
SQL> insert into matches values ('Peter',1,41);
insert into matches values ('Peter',1,41)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: error jeje
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.MATCHES_BIU_TEAM", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.MATCHES_BIU_TEAM'
```

I obtain that error.

Trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MATCHES_BIU_TEAM
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF team on matches
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  nContract_count  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO nContract_count
    FROM CONTRACTS_aux c
    WHERE c.PLAYER = :NEW.PLAYER AND
          c.TEAM BETWEEN :NEW.TEAM - 1
                     AND :NEW.TEAM + 1;

  IF nContract_count = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'error jeje');
  END IF;
END MATCHES_BIU_TEAM;
/
```

I dont know why appears that error..

Comment: Sorry, I write bad my code. Edited, this is not the problem

Comment: The error is your own application error when nContract_count = 0

Comment: But...really my trigger works? I only expected"ORA-20000: error jeje" that error

Comment: This is how Oracle (and SQL*Plus) report an error. Your trigger is working as designed